# Is the "cancel" button in Flink dashboard the same as the "kill application" button in yarn?

Tags: apache-flink, hadoop-yarn

Yarn:
[image]

Flink:
[image]

I am using flink 1.4.0, but let me know if anything changed in the later versions also.

From the documentation I was able to find this:
[image]

But I don't know which command the "Cancel" button in Flink Dashboard or the "Kill application" button in yarn uses.

Comment: I don't have **kill** application in Yarn RM (I thing I have not enough rights or version is different) but I think Yarn will kill container with Flink and it's a bit ungraceful  when if you cancel your job in Flink UI you TM's will finish their tasks before quit.

Comment: @Niko thanks for your comment, yes, I think it's like that as well, but I want proof and I want to know how it works exactly.

Comment: While they aren't the same, I don't think there's a meaningful difference. In both cases the job will suddenly and rudely no longer be running.